# ASP.NET Core Identity - MFA Verification code invalid after adding Identity Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

Working on ASP.NET Core with built-in 2FA code generator for the Microsoft Authenticator App.

Worked fine initially, generating a static Authenticator used to setup the Authenticator app.

I've since changed the location of my local database and imported the Identity Scaffolding.

When I tried to setup 2FA again after making these changes, it no longer worked and would instead generate a new Authenticator code after every failure. Every time I tried to setup 2FA with the Authenticator code, I would receive the following error: "Verification code invalid".

I looked into this issue briefly and found some people saying it was because the server and the phone were out of sync. However, I tested it on another test project and was surprised when the 2FA stopped working after adding the Identity Scaffolding.

I haven't really found anyone with a similar issue to this so I decided to try my luck here.

If anything is unclear, I am willing to provide more information.

Thanks.

Comment: TOTP (Time-based One-Time Password) authentication depends on both the server and authenticator device having an accurate time. Tokens only last for 30 seconds. If TOTP 2FA logins are failing, check that the server time is accurate. Besides, you can also check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [the sample](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreHybridFlowWithApi). You can compare it with yours.

Comment: I took a look at the sample and read over the document and I'm still not sure what the issue is. The code as far as both the EnableAuthenticator.cshtml.cs and TwoFactorAuthentication.cshtml.cs look to be the same. I also checked the time of my server at it seems to be in sync with the machine's time so I have no clue what might cause this.